# Чтение данных из очереди сообщений C#, Delphi, C++

Tags: c#, c++, delphi

Имеються две программы Windows Forms. Одна из них ежесекундно считывает данные с контроллера (написана на C++). Вторая (Delphi) при нажатии на соответствующие кнопки отсылает сообщение с помощью SendMessage, окну первой формы. Форма на С++ выдает соответствующие данные и в свою очередь вызывает SendMessage.
Обе программы работают коряво.

Задание состоит не трогая программу C++ отображать данные в программе на C#.

Я так понимаю, SendMessage работает с очередью сообщений Windows. Но по коду мне непонятно как они хранятся. То-есть они как бы выбрасываються в поток и потом форма их получает и обрабатывает с помощью своего обработчика?

C# имеет Message Queueing, но там речь идет о том, что сообщения храняться в ActiveDirectory. То-есть сообщение, например, по умолчанию это xml-файл. А данные из него получить можно, вызвав Queue.Receive(), а создание очереди требует путь к ней. То-есть, выходит разный подход к обработке данных.

Это разные принципы работы? Или я что-то не понимаю?

Можно ли получить из програмы на C# данные выдаваемые программой на C++? Ведь способы взаимодействия посредством PipeLine или  требуют изменения кода программы на C++.

```
// Обработчик в Delphi коде:
procedure TfEdit.GetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
tAsk.Enabled := true;
wAsked := (Sender as TBitBtn).Tag;
SendMessage(FindWindow('ControllerForm', 'Контроллер'), WM_WEIGHT, (Sender as TBitBtn).Tag, Handle);
end;

// Обработчик в C++ коде:
void __fastcall ControllerForm::nWndProc(Messages::TMessage &Message)
{
 int w;
 int WeightSt;
 if (Message.Msg == WM_WEIGHT)
 {
    if (Message.WParam == 0)
    {
      GetWeight(Weights[0], w); // чтение с контроллера
      if (WeightIsSet1)
        {WeightSt = 0;}
      else
        {WeightSt = 2;}
      SendMessage((HANDLE)Message.LParam, WM_WEIGHT, (WPARAM)WeightSt, (LPARAM)w);
    }
```

Comment: Узнаю блин, хайтек 80lvl, написанный дяденьками, имеющими о winapi представление, сформированное по книжкам о Windows 3.1. 
Исходники есть?

Comment: @gbg, есть какие-то , остатки файлов

Comment: @gbg, попробую отредактировать ответ

Comment: В C# можно напрямую использовать [WndProc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально, это устроено так - у приложения есть цикл, в котором оно вызывает `GetMessages()`.

Ну и потом длинная конструкция `switch/case`, которая и определяет дальнейшее поведение программы.

Сообщения действительно выстраиваются в очередь, так что уж не знаю, что там у вас глючит и каким образом.

Так как на C# можно вызвать любую функцию WinAPI, вы можете реализовать прием и отправку этих сообщений у себя в приложении - создаете окошко, добиваетесь, чтобы программа на C++ была в состоянии ваше окошко найти,  дальше разбираетесь с тем, что она шлет

Comment: То-есть придется менять код на С++ чтобы было взаимодействие с формой на C#. Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Боллее того, в любом случае надо будет менять код на С++, выдающий данные?

Comment: Для с# обычно используют коробочное решение - библиотеку forms. Если вы не используете коробку или она вам не подходит - то прийдется так сложно реализовывать.

Comment: @nick_n_a, как раз forms используеться в моем приложении. Но, хотелось бы знать, надо ли менять исходник на C++ для метода предложенного выше Прошу прощение, если не так формулирую вопрос. С Delphi и C++ совершенно не знаком.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что проще взять протокол девайса и написать все на C#, выкинув лишние звенья

Comment: Сложно оценить, зависит от ситуации. Если функционал теряется и он ну очень нужен - то прийдётся добавлять кучу кода.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответі